# If I have $F(x)=\int_{0}^{f(x)}h(t)dt$, with $f \in C^1$, calculate $\frac{dF}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> **Problem:** If $F(x)=\int_{0}^{f(x)}h(t)dt$, with $f \in C^1$, calculate $\frac{dF}{dx}$.

We can assume that $F(x)$ is well defined for $[0, f(x)]$, and that $h$ is continuous. I know that in general, $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x}h(t)dt=h(x)$. But in this case, the $f(x)$ is confusing me. This turns out to be $\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{f(x)}h(t)dt$, and suddenly I'm not sure if I can use the nice equation above anymore for this derivative. How can I calculate this integral?

Comment: Under suitable conditions, your problem is just a special case of the general differentiation under integral sign: $\frac{d}{dx} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,dt \right) = f\big(x,b(x)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{dx} b(x) - f\big(x,a(x)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{dx} a(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t) \,dt$ with $f(x,t) = h(t)$, $a(x) =0$, $b(x) = f(x)$ and this is proven using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @akech since $h(t)$ is defined in terms of one variable, how would I be able to generalize this to $h(x,t)$ then do all of $h(x, b(x))$ and $h(x, 0)$?

Comment: No. You do not have to generalize h. it is the f(x,t) which happens to be the function of t alone, namely, h(t). This makes your life easier because differentiating f(x,t) = h(t) with respect to x would give you what? (yes, zero).

Comment: Aha. I had looked at this previously, which is the Leibniz Integral rule if I'm not mistaken, but disregarded it as it looked like it didn't suit this problem. I see now that the partial derivative disappears and it reduces to the expressions below. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about it, is to let $I(t) = \int h(t) dt$ so 
$$
F(x) = \int_0^{f(x)} h(t) dt = I(f(x)) - I(0).
$$
Note that $I'(t) = h(t)$. Therefore, 
$$
\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \left[I(f(x)) - I(0) \right].
$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Got it, thanks. So I arrive at $\frac{dF}{dx}=h(f(x))f'(x)$, is this correct?

Comment: @user102938 yes, i agree

Answer (score 2):

Using what you've stated yourself, if you let $f(x) = y$, you would have

$$\frac{d}{dy} \int_{0}^{y}h(t)dt = h(y) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, using $F(x) = \int_{0}^{f(x)}h(t)dt$, you get

$$\frac{dF(x)}{df(x)} = h(f(x)) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), you have

$$\frac{dF(x)}{dx} = \frac{dF(x)}{df(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

I trust you can finish the rest.

Comment: Also a great explanation, thanks. So I arrive at $\frac{dF}{dx}=h(f(x))f'(x)$, is this correct?

Comment: @user102938 You're welcome for the explanation. Also, yes your stated result is correct. Note you could also use [akech](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/169316/akech)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672308/if-i-have-fx-int-0fxhtdt-with-f-in-c1-calculate-fracdfd/3672317?noredirect=1#comment7546556_3672308) to determine the same thing, e.g., its $f(x,t)$ is your $h(t)$, so its $f(x,b(x))$ becomes your $h(f(x))$. The derivative factor of $\frac{d}{dx}b(x)$ is $f'(x)$ in your case, and the remaining terms are all $0$.